# find all functions $g(x)$ that will satisfy the equation $g'(x) = g(x) + \int_0^1 g(x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to prove or find all functions $g(x)$ that will satisfy the equation

$$g’(x)=g(x)+\int_0^1g(x)dx$$

The only progress I have made towards an answer is that I rewrote $g’(x)=g(x)+G(1)-G(0)$. I have been staring at this for some time now, but can’t come up with anything.

Comment: Notice that $\int_0^1g(x){\rm d}x$ is just a constant so solve $g'(x) = g(x) + c$ and given the solution apply the constraint $c = \int_0^1g(x){\rm d}x$.

Comment: The equation to be solved should rather be written, in the question and in the accepted answer below, as
$$g’(x)=g(x)+\int_0^1g(t)dt.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiate. We are given that

$$g’(x)=g(x)+\int_{0}^{1}{g(x)}\,dx\implies g’’(x)=g’(x)$$

Therefore,

$$g’(x)=c_1e^x\implies g(x)=c_2+c_1e^x$$

$$\therefore c_1e^x=\left(c_2+c_1e^x\right)+\int_{0}^{1}{\left(c_2+c_1e^x\right)}\,dx=c_2+c_1e^x+c_2+c_1e-c_1$$

$$\therefore c_2=\frac{c_1(1-e)}{2}$$

Therefore,
$$g(x)=\frac{c_1(1-e)}{2}+c_1e^x$$

Comment: So all solutions will be of that form. Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if you differentiate the equation* you get $g''(t) = g'(t)$, which has the general solution $g'(t) = ce^t$. Integrating again, you get $g(t) = ce^t + d$; you can now use the original equation to find an appropriate choice of constants.

---

*Any solution $g$ is smooth enough to differentiate as many times as necessary, so this is valid.

Comment: Why is $*$ true? To get the solution you have to start with the ansatz that $g''$ exists?

Comment: @charlestoncrabb Assume there's a differentiable solution $g$. By examining the original equation, we can conclude that $g'$ (which is just $g + $ constant) is also differentiable. Repeat the logic to conclude that $g$ has a third derivative, and so on. In this manner, $g \in C^{\infty}$.

Comment: Dig it. I guess it's been a long day.